# Classes imported in .pch file in xcode not working, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a concern with my .pch file in Xcode 5.

I have following code in my .pch file--

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

#import <Example/Example.h>

#endif
```

But when i use Example.h class in my code it is not working.
When i use code like-

```
[Example sharedInstance];
```

xcode shows error "Use od undeclared identifier Example".
What is the problem?

Comment: Is the preprocessor/compiler able to see the header? Is it a system provided framework, 3rd party or your own? Have you included the path to the header in the 'Header Search Path' build settings?

Comment: It is 3rd party framework.

Comment: @ Jasarien Thanks!!!! Problem solved..I include path in  'Header Search Path' build settings..and it is done...

Comment: I added the solution as an answer, please accept it if it solved your issue.

Comment: If you are using `cocoapods`. You may checkout this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42965407/1179642).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to include the path to the headers in the "Header Search Path" build settings so that the preprocessor/compiler can find the headers.

Comment: You also need to check always search header search path ON

Answer (score 16):

This **Screen Shot** from **XCode 6.1** shows how I got this to work - and therefore may prove helpful.

Look at the bold text, mid-way down, in the **"Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language"** TARGETS / Build Settings area.

Notice how the bold text **"Precompile Prefix Header"** has been set to **YES**, and the path to the pch file in **"Prefix Header"** is set with **ProjectName/YourPCHFile-Prefix.pch**

[image: Screen Shot from XCode 6.1 showing how to include .pch file]