# PrefixHeader.pch file can't find headers

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a small prefix header file

```
#ifndef UP_FOR_IT_PrefixHeader_pch
#define UP_FOR_IT_PrefixHeader_pch

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <Parse/Parse.h>
    #import "ABConstants.h"
    #import "ABCache.h"
    #endif
#endif
```

it can't find Parse.h. I linked it from `Link binary with libraries` everything seems right but whatever I tried it does't compile. I tried removing the lib and import again but nothing changed. Removed indexes on derived data but still no clue.

What should I try? It took 2 hours and still not working.

Xcode 6. IOS 8

Comment: I have the same issue since I moved to XCode 6. My project was created (and compiles fine) with XCode 5, but for some reason, with XCode 6, the external libraries (added with Cocoapods) can't be imported from the .pch file (saying "file not found"). If I import them from outside (AppDelegate e.g.), it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select your project (named "Project" for example) and click on "ProjectTests" (in TARGETS section). 
Then, go to Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries and add Parse.framework

Comment: This solved my problem, although it was Crashlytics instead of Parse

Comment: also got me past that compile error, but it turns out i need to add every framework that's in the main project to the test targets before it will run even the simplest test

Answer (score 7):

Goto **Build Settings** > **Apple LLVM 6.0** - Language > **Prefix Header**

Add here:  **$(SRCROOT)/PrefixHeader.pch**

[image]

**If $(SRCROOT) not working for you**, set the value of '*Prefix Header*' to your PCH file name, with the project name - i.e. for project named '*Test-Project*' and PCH file named '*Test-Project-Prefix.pch*' and add the complete string '*Test-Project/Test-Project-Prefix.pch*'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case rest of the answers doesn't work for someone. Try changing Under "Target Membership", the scope of your targets from public to project. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cocoapods`, you may checkout this [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2671).
I got this problem but none of the solution above worked for me.

I'm using cocoapods, the reason is that in the Podfile I only linked pods to default `target`. If you are going to add another one, you should add another target configuration in Podfile(`target:'target' do`). Usually the new one is the same to the original one, you could use `link_with` to make life easier.

But life is not always that easy. It looks like that `link_with` is deprecated. You may checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280077/error-with-cocoapods-link-with-after-update-to-1-0-0).