# Error with cocoapods link_with after update to 1.0.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have updated cocoapods today to 1.0.0 version. I got this string when I update the pods:

`[!] Invalid Podfile file: [!] The specification of link_with in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..`

I have removed link_with in my podFile but I can't build the project because I have many Match-O-Linkers. Any one knows how should I fix this problem?

This is my Podfile right now:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!


pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3'
    pod 'ARAnalytics' , :subspecs => ["Crashlytics", "Amplitude", "DSL"]
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.10.1'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.10.1'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.10.1'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'Branch'

    pod 'Leanplum-iOS-SDK'

    pod 'Fabric', '1.6.7'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '3.7.0'
    pod 'TwitterKit'
    pod 'Digits'

    target 'minubeTests' do
      pod 'OCMockito'
    end
```

Comment: The solution with `def ... end` is NOT recommended according to CocoaPods core team presentation on 13th June 2016 at San Francisco. The recommended solution is `abstract_target ... do ... end`.

Comment: Accepted answer is not the right one.

Comment: Does not mean its right.

Comment: just perfect, i separated my pods in two def and it's good for watch, widget and app, thx !

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this. Works for me with more than one target.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

def myPods
    pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
    pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3'
    pod 'ARAnalytics' , :subspecs => ["Crashlytics", "Amplitude", "DSL"]
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.10.1'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.10.1'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.10.1'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'Branch'

    pod 'Leanplum-iOS-SDK'

    pod 'Fabric', '1.6.7'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '3.7.0'
    pod 'TwitterKit'
    pod 'Digits'
end

target 'yourTargetOne' do
    myPods
end

target 'yourTargetTwo' do
    myPods
end

target 'minubeTests' do
    pod 'OCMockito'
end
```

Comment: This is not official documented approach.

Comment: worth an up vote for a working solution but not officially documented Cocoapods approach

Comment: The solution with `def ... end` is NOT recommended according to CocoaPods core team presentation on 13th June 2016 at San Francisco. The recommended solution is `abstract_target ... do ... end`.

Comment: Would love to know a specific reason _why_ this is not recommended... an article link would suffice.

Comment: You should always use the official documented approach. This is not the one. Check my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/37598195/4153728

Answer (score 31):

**According to the new official CocoaPods [specification](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) since version 1.0 the new model is this:**

> Note that `BasePods` is not the actual name of any target in the project.

*`TargetNameOne` and `TargetNameTwo` are the real names.*

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
inhibit_all_warnings!

abstract_target 'BasePods' do
    ## Networking
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'

    # Twitter
    pod 'TwitterKit', '~> 1.9'
    pod 'Fabric'

    # Specify your actual targets
    target 'TargetNameOne'
    target 'TargetNameTwo'
end
```

*Edit* - There is an implicit abstract target at the root of the `Podfile` now, so you could write the above example as:

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
inhibit_all_warnings!

## Networking
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'

# Twitter
pod 'TwitterKit', '~> 1.9'
pod 'Fabric'

# Specify your actual targets
target 'TargetNameOne'
target 'TargetNameTwo'
```

- *This is for multiple targets which is the most common case, but can be used for single target as well and I like one universal pattern.*

Comment: Thank you , your answer resolved my issue.Pod version 1.0.1

Comment: This works, also I had to change xcodeproj to project

Comment: This is the correct answer per cocoapods documentation.

Answer (score 2):

With the new [specification](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html). all your pod include should be specified target based.
Change your pod file to

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

# change minube to whatever name is of you main target
target 'minube' do
  pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3'
  pod 'ARAnalytics' , :subspecs => ["Crashlytics", "Amplitude", "DSL"]
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.10.1'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.10.1'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.10.1'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  pod 'Branch'

  pod 'Leanplum-iOS-SDK'

  pod 'Fabric', '1.6.7'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '3.7.0'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'Digits'
end
target 'minubeTests' do
  pod 'OCMockito'
end
```