# How can I replace link_with with target blocks?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have updated cocoapods today to 1.0.0 version. I got this string when I update the pods:

`[!] Invalid`Podfile`file: [!] The specification of`link_with`in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..`

The content of my Pod file is

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'QuickStart' do
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!

# Pods for QuickStart
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
link_with ['QuickStart']
xcodeproj 'QuickStart'
pod 'ADALiOS', :git => 'https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc.git', :branch=> 'convergence'
pod 'NXOAuth2Client'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
link_with ['QuickStart']
xcodeproj 'QuickStart'
pod 'ADALiOS'
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with cocoapods link\_with after update to 1.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280077/error-with-cocoapods-link-with-after-update-to-1-0-0)

Comment: Surprisingly, this document has not been updated even after 3 years.  I have the same problem on the same MS page.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-ios